# Should I lag explanatory variables in regression with apparently strong predictive relationship?

Tags: regression, correlation, predictive-models, r-squared, lm

I'm no expert when it comes to statistics (learning though) and I am working on developing a multiple linear regression model in an attempt to forecast sales revenue.

I feel like I may have developed a decent predictive model, but the point was made to me that perhaps the explanatory variables should be lagged because the revenue is booked several weeks prior to product being manufactured.  Thus in reality the production figures do not align with their directly associated revenue.  The lag would be anywhere from 1-2 months.

N_A represents monthly North American vehicle production and US_PCE represents an index of monthly U.S. Consumer Expenditures excluding food and energy.  Monthly revenue is the response variable.

So I have 2 main questions:

- Is my correlation spurious?
- Should I lag my predictors?

[image: Model Summary]

Comment: The problem that you are going to face is that it seems that the revenue at time $t$ is most closely linked to production at time $t+1$ or $t+2$, which of course you won't know at times prior to $t$ when you have to generate the forecast.   This doesn't ruin your ability to forecast, but it does indicate that a different type of model - time series, or multivariate time series perhaps - will likely perform better.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Ben! You might find this article useful: De Boef, S. and Keele, L. (2008). [Taking time seriously](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3a3e/d25148f942dc6038a1fb45bcb759575106a4.pdf). *American Journal of Political Science*, 52(1):184–200. $$\phantom{0}$$And if/when you are ready for a deeper dive into time series models: Banerjee, A., Dolado, J. J., Galbraith, J. W., and Hendry, D. F. (1993). *Co-integration, error correction, and the econometric analysis of non-stationary data*. Oxford University Press, USA.